# Server 2008 continues to register NIC's in DNS

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I have a Server 2008 R2 box running Hyper-V, hosting VM's.  I have 4 NIC's set up - the primary network NIC, 1 NIC for the SAN, and 2 NIC's for the virtual machines.  The 2 NIC's for the virtual machines continue to register in DNS despite having the Register this Connection in DNS checkbox cleared.  I am running a Windows Server 2003 Domain with AD-Integrated Zones.

Even after I delete the A records for the 2 NIC's for the virtual machines, they continue to re-appear in DNS.

I am not sure how to stop this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Palm to forehead.  I rebooted the Server 08 box and the unwanted A records disappeared from DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Your DHCP server may be configured to register them on their behalf.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941150%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: DHCP is being served up by switches, not Windows.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you could also just restart the DNS Client service instead of a full reboot.